# DbEntityValidationException thrown in Azure for no reason

Tags: entity-framework-6, azure-sql-database

Sometimes (less than 1% of the calls I think) I get weird DbEntityValidationException exception thrown in Azure environment.

I have user which has Company, for sure it is existing as the code would otherwise crash earlier;

```
var user = _db.Users.Single(u => u.Id.Equals(userId));
_db.Entry(user).Reference(g => g.Company).Load(); // <-- Make sure its loaded
var company = user.Company;
```

Later that company is used when storing another entity, which has

```
[Required]
public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
```

And when calling SaveChanges() I get;

```
Exception: System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException 
InnerException: 
Message: Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details. The validation errors are: The Company field is required.
```

I've expected the problem to be Company lazy loading, as user has;

```
public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
```

I've tried to force EF6 to load it by accessing Company's properties or as you see above using Load()

But still the problem is there, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything that immediately jumps out... and unfortunately there isn't really a lot we can do to diagnose it without a way for us to reproduce it. The only idea that I have is perhaps you are sometimes getting a transient failure from SQL Azure that means the `Company` property doesn't actually get loaded. Have you tried enabling connection resiliency - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456835? This is always recommended when running against SQL Azure.